# How to turn off warning/error bars on APK build

Tags: build, warnings, flutter

I am using a `Hero` animation in my App. During the transition, the text receives a thick yellow underline. I'm pretty sure this is a overflow warning (or something similar), but it persists even when I run `flutter build apk` and `flutter install`, i.e. it exists in production builds.

My app functions fine, so I'd like to hide these. How do I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> During the transition, the text receives a thick yellow underline.

That is because `Hero` transition is done trough `Overlay`, which is rendered outside of `Scaffold` or other `Material` widgets.

The problem ? It means during transition, there's no widget that introduce a valid `Theme` (`Scaffold`, `Dialog`, `Material` do for example).
So it fallback to a default `Theme`. And that `Theme` has yellow underline with a big font.

The solution : Wrap your `Hero` child into a widget introducing `Theme` or in `Theme` itself.

Comment: Perfect! For future readers, I had to add `decoration: TextDecoration.none` to all my `Text` widgets, to revert the theme the hero transition widget recieved.

Answer (score 2):

These bars are only shown in debug build.

For release builds use

```
flutter build apk --release
```

Comment: That's not the problem actually

Comment: I'm aware that the overflow should be fixed but he explicitely asked how to just get rid of the yellow bar :D As far as I know they are not shown in release builds.

Comment: Yeah but it's not overflow he's talking about. It's about text having a yellow underline during hero transition.

Comment: I think I see now what you mean

Comment: As @RémiRousselet stated, I confused the overflow warnings with the default Hero transition behavior. However, flutter gives faux-warnings (i.e. it thinks there are sub-pixel overflows due to rounding errors), and this helped quell them. Cheers!